# Url Route asp.net

Tags: asp.net

my Model is

```
public class Organization
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my routeConfig

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Url",
        "{controller}/{action}/{Url}",
     new { controller = "Organization", action = "PageContent", Url = "" }
       );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Is there a way to fix the routing so that both Url and ID would work?
for example ...Organization/details/{ID} and ...Organization/details/{Url} would both work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As both the routes seems same you can combine both and define one and in the action (or onActionExecuting) you can decide the behavior based ID or URL

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{Segment}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Segment = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Or you can map the route with ID only and take URL as querystring.